# Как работает данный метод?

Tags: javascript, математика, случайные-числа

```
var discount = Math.floor((Math.random()*5) + 5);
```

Comment: какой у вас конкретно к этой формуле вопрос, кроме тех что можно явно прочитать в документации к функциям `floor` и `random`. Курс арифметики вызывает сложности?

Comment: @teran - почему Вы не упомянули операторы `*` и `+` и знаки `(`, `)` и `=`?

Comment: @Igor отнес их к арифметике :)

Comment: Ребят, а можно как-то поуважительней и терпеливей к новичкам. Не хотите отвечать — не отвечайте. Вот, в ответе всё разжевали за пару абзацев. И не надо закрывать по надуманным поводам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция `Math.random()` генерирует случайное число в диапазоне `[0;1)`
т.е., `0 <= Math.random() < 1`
умножаем на 5, получаем: `0 <= Math.random()*5 < 5`
прибавляем 5, получаем: `5 <= (Math.random()*5) + 5 < 10`
функция `Math.floor()` извлекает целую часть числа (согласно справке - возвращает наибольшее целое число, которое меньше либо равно аргументу),
соответственно, в переменную discount будет записано случайное число в диапазоне `[5;9]` (от 5 до 9, включая обе границы)